# Raspberry PI 3 B+ with 3G Pilot

Tags: pi-3, remote, connection, internet

Ive been trying to setup a 3G internet connection for my Pi using the Pi: PiloT.

I keep getting and ERROR on the minicom window when i run the command AT+XCEDATA=1,0, in order to start an IP session...

Does anyone have any experience in using the Pilot as a 3G connection? IF so could you please offer some advise on setup etc.

Comment: But PiloT does NOT support Rpi4B! https://linkwave.co.uk/pilot

Comment: @tlfong01 The question is clearly tagged `pi-3`

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev, Yes, you are right.  How come I made such a silly mistake?  Let me look back what happened.  (1)  I read the question.  (2) I never heard of PiloT, so I googled.  (3) I am only interested to solve Rpi4 questions, so if the question does not mention Rpi4, I won't bother to comment.  (4) So I read 2 times to make sure I did not misunderstand about PiloT's compatibility to Rpi4, before I pointed out the incompatibility.  (5)  When I read your comments, I immediately checked if the question has been edited, removing the word "Rpi4". But there is no record of editing,

Comment: Can you please confirm the following: (1) If the OP HIMSELF has edited the question, there will be no editing history showing in this question.

Comment: @tlfong01 The poster can edit their question for 5 minutes after publishing it without creating any history, so this doesn't seem to be the case. Please don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to catch you on a wrongdoing or pressure you into explaining yourself. I know you're trying to help. I expected that you'd simply delete your comment if you agree it's not relevant, and I'd delete mine.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev, No worries, I never thought that you are trying to catch me on a wrong doing.  Actually I was about to thank you for pointing out my possibly careless mistake. Actually just now I thought about the time lag problem.  This morning I skimmed the questions, and found this one interesting.  Their website is clear cut, listing Rpi 2/3 but no Rpi4.  So I immediately gave the comment (should be less than 5 minutes).

Comment: I found that the question was asked 17 hours ago, and my comments 8 hours ago, so IF the system is working to spec. The OP should have not edited the question.  In order not to embarrassed anybody, it would be nice if you can move both you and my comments to a private chat room, and we can continue my discussion there, nothing urgent.

Comment: Question has not been edited, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @R.Shaw, Thank you for your clarification.  My apologies for my wrong guess. I found this a bit weird, but I have no suggestions for now.