# How can Rpi connect to a GSM Module and send SMS messages?

Tags: gsm

This is my GSM Module:

[image]

Is anyone familiar on how to connect this to my Raspberry Pi 3? Is still all I need or I have something missing?

Comment: It would help us to have a link to more information on that particular module and a description of what you want the Pi to do with it.

Comment: Ah, let me see. The following Arduino connection might help: WARNING: No guarantee no nothing won't meltdown or blow up!: (1) https://imgur.com/gallery/k1kNe0v. Or you might like to read the following: (2) Sim800 Hardware Design
https://img.filipeflop.com/files/download/Datasheet_SIM800L.pdf

(3) Sim800 AT Command Set
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/sim800_series_at_command_manual_v1.01.pdf

(4) SimCom Sim800/900 GSM/GPRS Modules
https://www.espruino.com/SIM900. Happy connecting. Cheers.

Comment: And my answer to the following question might also help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104479/sim800-gsm-module-to-raspberry-pi-uart-serial-communication-problem.

Comment: @BobBrown I'm having a difficult time trying to find one. Even finding that image took me some time. I'll get back to you on that. But in terms of what I want to do, I just basically want to be able to send an sms message.

Comment: This AliExpress SIM800 catalog might help. https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-module-sim800.html.

Comment: @tlfong01 still no luck :(

Comment: @olivakyle, what do you mean by "no luck"?. No match found? Actually you don't need to look up the AliExpress catalog to find one matching your photo.  If your photo does match the real thing in hand, then there is no need to look further.  Look at the marking near the two pin yellow jumper. It says "SM800C". This means your module belongs to the SIM800 series. In other words, you module is in general (wiring, AT commands etc) compatible to almost all SIM800/900 cards  WARNING: No Guarantee no nothing won't melt down or blow up! Take my suggestion at your own risk!

Comment: @tlfong01 I'm still not able to find any references on how will I connect this to my Raspberry Pi 3 and how will I set it up.

Comment: And if what you want to do is SMS, then at least you need to read the 300+ pages AT Command Set Manual: (1) SIM800 Series AT Command Manual V1.01 - SIMCom SIM Tech 2003
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/sim800_series_at_command_manual_v1.01.pdf. Of course you don't read the 300+ pages from cover to cover. You only need to read the Contents page and follow my cheat sheet: (1) Section 2 - AT Commands (ITU-T V25.ter) - Page 21, 

(2) Section 5 - AT Commands for SIM Application Toolkit - Page 123 /to continue, ...

Comment: (3) Section 6 - Detailed descriptions of AT Commands, AT Commands specific to SIMCom - Page 130 (Page 146~153 SMS)

(4) Section 20 - AT Command Examples Page 297 (Page 302 SMS Commands). Happy friendly manual reading:) Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104296/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-olivakyle).

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the SIM800 GSM chip. This needs to be connected to the serial port (UART) on the Raspberry Pi (make sure that the voltage levels on the SIM 800 and RPi pins are the same or you'll end up bricking either or both the devices).

Once that is done, you will have to use the "AT Commands" to write a program that communicates with the SIM800 over serial. Here's an AT command reference manual - https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf

Comment: By any chance do you know what voltage level this one requires? I'm having trouble to find a document for this chip.

Comment: Per the hardware design guide (https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM800/SIM800_Hardware%20Design_V1.09.pdf) the digital pins are rated for 3V on page 53. There's a your module already has a voltage converter installed between the header and the module pins, if not follow the recommendations on page 30-31 for appropriate voltage levels.

Comment: upon checking I see this is a SIM800**C**. Is this still applicable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a GSM HAT?   It will be faster, easier and less damage risk to your pi.  The final product will also be neatly stacked.

[image]

If your rPi has internet access, then you could try an internet SMS gateway (Twilio etc.) and skip the GSM radio